# How do I annotate the Type of a custom Request header?

Tags: javascript, node.js, flowtype

I have an endpoint that takes a custom `header` of `string` type.

I'm using `Flow` for type annotations, but I'm not sure how to add an annotation onto a custom property of a native `Type` like this.

For example, my function is:

```
function(req: Request) {
  const custom = req.headers.custom_header;
}
```

`Flow` reports that `the property custom_header is not found in Header`.

I tried using a type declaration a few different ways:

`declare var Request.headers.custom_header: string`
`declare var req.headers.custom_header: string`

But neither seemed to affect the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Headers` is not just an object, however. There is a [`Headers.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/get) method which does what you think it would, and type checks.

```
function parse(req: Request) {
  const custom = req.headers.get('custom_header');
}
```